# How to fix an offset audio?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I'm working on a music video.

I came back from a break on this projet and started to work on new stuff when I realised, 3 days later, that the audio was offset.
I think it's a weird offset, a kinda sliding one but my computer is not optimised for 3D work and I struggle to really comprehend what's going on as exports are fairly long and all the elements that allow the sync between audio and video are not visible in the viewport unless in material or render mode which slow down my computer.

Long story short, I'm at a point where I studied an older version of the same file to figure out what changed.
In this version, I cannot manage to toggle the audio but its strip exists in the video sequencer and displays some differences with my current file when I look into the specs.
I guess the answer lies in those values but I don't fully know what I'm looking at.
[image]

What does this 5734 value represents?
I guess it's the duration of the clip but how can it be different that the one in my old file?
Same source, same starting point, same ending point.
Also, despite both playheads being at the 160th frame, the current version is at the 06:10 mark while the old one is at 06:16.

Can someone explain to me what's happening, how to fix this and, if possible, how did I managed to get there without trying to.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
Here are the info I'm getting when I open the file song with MediaInfo, if it's any help:
[image]

Comment: 5734 is the number of frames. Since this number has changed, but not the duration, my guess is that your file has a variable frame rate. You can check this with the Media Info software. If it has vfr, it needs to be re-encoded in ex. handbrake to a steady frame-rate.

Comment: You're talking about the song file, right ?
I've downloaded MediaInfo and put the song through it and, well, i'm not getting the information needed. No mention of VFR or EX. I've updated my post with a screen shot.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice it was the audio file. I a bit clueless why the duration is kept but the number of frames differ. Is the frame rate the same in both files?

Comment: That's it! Thank you so so much, all is back in order. Do you think it's possible that I've changed it by an accidental hot key or is it clear that I've changed it consciously and don't remember it ? Thanks anyway, you made my day.